# Update taxonomy field value with REST

Tags: taxonomy, rest

I'm getting the following error when trying to update a taxonomy field value via REST api:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientServiceException",
    "message": {
      "lang": "en-US",
      "value": "Cannot deserialize data for type Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValueCollection."
    }
  }
}
```

The request:

```
https://server/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/Shared Documents/file.txt')/ListItemAllFields

{
  "__metadata": {
    "type": "SP.Data.Shared_x0020_DocumentsItem"
  },
  "Title": "some title",
  "Project": {
    "results": [
      {
        "Label": "Term1",
        "TermGuid": "897bdf7f-08d6-44b9-a71a-ddc4cf131664",
        "WssId": 5
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The REST API does not currently support working with Managed Metadata or Taxonomy fields. The JavaScript Client Object Model does, if you're looking for an alternative.

Comment: Rob: Is it possible to filter by a taxonomy column? Something like &$select=Score/WssId &$expand=Score/WssId &$filter=Score/TermGuid eq 7f4bd49f-8dbc-4e6f-a165-cbdf4b0ba7d1. I'm trying to do this following AC's post here: http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/Applying-Filters-to-Lookup-Fields-with-the-SP2013-REST-API

Comment: Don't suppose that this is coming soon?

Comment: Are you sure it's not just multi-fields which are not supported? It works fine with __TaxonomyFieldType__, just not with multi. If the field was a single field it would look something like: `Project: { __metadata: { type: "SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue" }, TermGuid: "897bdf7f-08d6-44b9-a71a-ddc4cf131664", WssId: -1 }` . I am not able to make it work for __TaxonomyFieldTypeMulti__.

Comment: While you may be able to get certain things to work, it is not something that is documented or officially supported. If you look at the REST API reference you'll find no mention of SP.Taxonomy or anything under SP.Taxonomy  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569.aspx

Comment: Just noticed Marc's comment (even though it's from 2013). The answer is yes, you can filter on a managed metadata column if you use a CAML Query.  http://www.cleverworkarounds.com/2013/09/23/how-to-filter-on-a-managed-metadata-column-via-rest-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: This is an old thread, but still one of the top Google results for this topic.  I found this article really useful:  https://blog.hubfly.com/update-managed-metadata-field-through-rest-api-in-sharepoint-framework