# Update metadata field of type TaxonomyFieldValueCollection using REST API

Tags: rest, managed-metadata, taxonomy

While updating metadata of field type `TaxonomyFieldValueCollection` I am getting following error.

> "{"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientServiceException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Cannot deserialize data for type Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValueCollection."}}}"

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/73079/update-taxonomy-field-value-with-rest